# How can I get the timestamp when a Contact enters a journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, journeybuilder, data-views

I am building reporting using SQL Activities. SQL is bucketing success events into tranches that represent the time window for a communication to claim success- i.e. email 1 is from 0 to 24 hours, email 2 is from 24-72 hours, etc.

I have a journey where about 60% of the contacts achieve success before the 1st communication. Which DataView can I find the EventDate for a contact entering a Journey? I want the complete list. If I use the first communication _Sent EventDate, this will exclude contacts that did not reach this point in the Journey.

Is it possible to get the timestamp for when a contact enters a Journey using SQL? If not, how?